# SELinux security context of parent directories

Tags: rhel, selinux, linux-audit

I'm using a RHEL machine with SELinux enabled.

I'd like to change the logfile position of `auditd` to `/mydir/log/audit.log`. I can apply the security context `system_u:object_r:auditd_log_t:s0` to this file. However, what should be the security context of the directory `/mydir/log` and parent directory `/mydir` since they're going to be read/written by other daemons?

Or should I just go the least complicated way and do

```
semanage permissive -a auditd_t
```

instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mostly there, you're using the `semanage` command.
Since you already know that there's a correct context on /var/log/audit, the easiest thing is to set up a local selinux filecontext equivalence.  So you'd run something like this:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/log/audit /mydir/log
```

This tells SELinux to add (-a) a file context rule that says that /mydir/log will have all the equivalent (-e) file context as /var/log/audit.  Once you've set the rule, you want to run `restorecon -r -v /mydir/log` to set the selinux attributes on /mydir/log to what the new policy wants.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify that you have disabled log rotation, so we still need to allow auditd to create multiple files.

More generally, you should keep the current structure of putting the audit logs in a dedicated `audit` directory, unless you are very confident about why you don't need to do so.  Unless your version does not use that structure, because it is old?  But at least RHEL 6 uses `/var/log/audit/` by default.

Provided you don't allow anything to rename or change permissions of any of the ancestor directories, it is sufficiently restrictive to have `auditd_log_t` on `audit.log` and the `audit` log directory.

The above seems straightforward to fulfil. Then "sufficiently restrictive" would mean you can consider the security part of the decision solved.  Just test whatever and see if it works, and then you'll know it is not *too* restrictive. I didn't notice any difficulty here, from the information you gave.